# Details action not working in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to make a website with asp.net mvc 4 & entity framework 6 where user can see their profile details by clicking `Profile` button. But everytime I try to `Login` I get error like below. If I comment out the `ProfileView` section then I can login. My code is below,

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ProfileView(int UserId=0)
{
  UserInfo profile = db.UserInfoes.Find(UserId);
  if (Session["UserBOID"] != null)
  {
    return View(profile);
  }
  else
  {
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
  }
}
```

**View**

```
@model ABCoLtd.Models.MkistatVsUserLogin
@if (@Session["UserBOID"] != null)
{
  <li>Welcome, <b>@Session["UserBOID"].ToString()</b></li>
  foreach(var item in Model)
  {
    <li><a class="btn btn-info" href="@Url.Action("ProfileView", "Home", new { UserId=item.UserId })" target="_blank"><b>Profile</b></a></li>
  }
}
```

**Custom Model to use different table under same model**

```
public class MkistatVsUserLogin
{
    public IEnumerable<UserInfo> UserInfo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<mkistat> mkistats { get; set; }
}
```

Is there something wrong in my code? If so, please give me a solution since I need this help badly. Your help will be appreciated. Tnx.

**UPDATES**

**Error**

> Compilation Error
>    Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required
>    to service this request. Please review the following specific error details
>    and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'ABCoLtd.Models.MkistatVsUserLogin' because 'ABCoLtd.Models.MkistatVsUserLogin' does not contain a public definition for     'GetEnumerator'
>
> Source Error:
>   Line 37: foreach(var item in Model)

Comment: It would be very nice if you would actually share the error you get.

Comment: Post the details of the error details! But your return typeof `UserInfo` to the view, but the view expects `MkistatVsUserLogin`. Your need to change one  or the other (they need to be the same type)

Comment: Please check my updates.

Comment: Where is UserId defined? You're model is not a collection!

Comment: And sorry the problem is in Login, but if I comment out the profileview section from view then I can login. So I assume my problem is in my profileview method.

Comment: You haven't even posted the correct code, but clearly if the view is correct and your model is `MkistatVsUserLogin` then it would need to be `foreach (var item in Model.UserInfo) { ...`. And edit your question with the correct code!!

Comment: And learn to format you question!!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing only one object from controller to view so you need to change it to collection if you want to loop on it.

```
  UserInfo profile = db.UserInfoes.Find(UserId);//This is only one object
```

Comment: If I use one object then how can I use view to redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Change `Model` to `Model.UserInfo`, like:

```
 @model ABCoLtd.Models.MkistatVsUserLogin
 @if (@Session["UserBOID"] != null)
 {
    <li>Welcome, <b>@Session["UserBOID"].ToString()</b></li>
    foreach(var item in Model.UserInfo) <<---
    {
       <li><a class="btn btn-info" href="@Url.Action("ProfileView", "Home", new { UserId=item.UserId })" target="_blank"><b>Profile</b></a></li>
    }
 }
```

You have to use the collection `Model.UserInfo` in your loop instead of the view model itself.

Comment: I did it exactly what you said, now I get this error, `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Then `UserInfo` is `null`. Your need to initialize it (and add some value to the list)!

Comment: Like Stephen said, make sure it is NOT null by setting it in your controller.

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry for asking, I'm new in asp.net

Comment: I suggest you first read a bit about MVC, because these are the very basics. In your controller you construct your view model, which is passed to the view. While constructing the view model, initialize your UserInfo instance so that it contains elements.

Comment: I found in table that `UserId` field is set to varchar. So does putting int in controller might causing the error? And if it is, how can I solve it?

Comment: Then UserId should be a string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are passing **UserInfo** object to view

```
UserInfo profile = db.UserInfoes.Find(UserId);
```

Problem is that your view expects **MkistatVsUserLogin** model

```
@model ABCoLtd.Models.MkistatVsUserLogin
```

You have to pass **MkistatVsUserLogin** object to view in ProfileView ActionResult and make UserInfo List to be able to add objects to collection.

```
public class MkistatVsUserLogin
{
  public List<UserInfo> UserInfo { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<mkistat> mkistats { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult ProfileView(int UserId=0)
{
  UserInfo profile = db.UserInfoes.Find(UserId);
  MkistatVsUserLogin model = new MkistatVsUserLogin();
  model.UserInfo = new List<UserInfo>();
  model.UserInfo.Add(profile);
  if (Session["UserBOID"] != null)
  {
    return View(model);
  }
  else
  {
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
  }
}
```

Now second problem is in your view. You are looping **MkistatVsUserLogin** model and you should loop **UserInfo** collection

```
  foreach(var item in Model.UserInfo)
  {
    <li><a class="btn btn-info" href="@Url.Action("ProfileView", "Home", new { UserId=item.UserId })" target="_blank"><b>Profile</b></a></li>
  }
```

Comment: Hi, tnx for your help but I still get this error, `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: In the database table `UserId` is set as VARCHAR(50). So is this the cause of error? If so, What is the solution?

Comment: well you can change UserId to int and check. UserId should be primary key in your Db and you should define it as integer

Comment: But I must set it to varchar. So what variable type should I use in controller?

Comment: and in your code I don't see mkistats object where do you use it. it can throw object reference if you try to loop through it as it is null becouse you did not initialize it

Comment: you need string type if UserId is Varchar in database

Comment: mkistats object is working fine. Its just the profileview problem.

Comment: So should I use `public ActionResult ProfileView(string UserId)` like this?

Comment: Yes you have to pass string UserId and also you must DEBUG your code. I am pretty sure you will find out where it throws object reference exception, if you debug : )